# Scroll Box for Data Entry - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I am trying to create a data entry form that will be used in my company when filing for travel reimbursements. Part of the excel sheet asks for expenses per day. Knowing that the number of days traveled by an employee can vary, I would like to create something similar to a scroll-box so that this section of the form does not take up too much space.

Instead, I would like to only show 5 rows of this section and if more is needed, have a scrollbar that would show more empty rows that can be filled in. Is there any way to do this?
[image: Screenshot]
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyRoJ.jpg)

Comment: In Access, you can create a form and embed a table in the form to do this. In Excel, this doesn't exist. The closest thing I can recall is the View -> Freeze Panes on the desired row. The top of the horizontal line will be static while the bottom of the Frozen Pane will scroll. So you would Freeze Pane at row 31 (in your example), then scroll the sheet to row 65 (in your example).

Comment: @e.casas If any of the answer(s) you have received answers your question, be sure to mark the answer accordingly for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0):

**Excel's Split View feature is what you are looking for:**

1. On the *View* tab of Excel's ribbon, click **Split**
   [image]
2. The worksheet window will be split into four sections.  Since you only need a top and bottom section, double-click the vertical split bar to remove it
   [image]
3. Now you may drag the horizontal split bar to show as much or as little of the top portion of the worksheet as you wish.

**Note:** This solution allows the top *and* bottom panes of your window to be scrolled.  Unfortunately in Excel it's not possible to prevent the user from scrolling the bottom pane.

Comment: Commenting your note: The "Freeze Panes" button right beside "Split" in your screenshot does not allow you to ?

Comment: @Darksoulpk68 The Freeze Panes will freeze the *top* pane and allow the user to scroll the bottom pane. Based on the OPs screen shot, he wants the opposite...which cannot be done with Freeze Panes.

Comment: Well, this could certainly be a good request to Microsoft ! Thank you :)

Comment: @Darksoulpk68 Agreed. BTW, I see you're new to Super User. Glad to have you. Love the profile pic too...